# How to select the right TVS/fuse combination?

Tags: switching-regulator, tvs, ptc

I am working on a design featuring the MP1495S switching regulator. The regulator will take 12 V and output 5 V. The maximum current I want to allow at the output of the regulator is 3 A.

1. Am I correct in thinking that this implies a max. current of 1.25 A at 12 V at the input?
2. I want to protect the input of the regulator using a PTC and a TVS, and need help selecting the correct ones. Would the [0ZCG0260FF2C](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/bel-fuse-inc/0ZCG0260FF2C/507-1778-1-ND/4156282) combined with the [SMBJ12A](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/fairchild-on-semiconductor/SMBJ12A/SMBJ12AFSCT-ND/2094445) work?

I looked at the electrical characteristics of the 0ZCG0260FF2C but I don't fully understand how the rated voltage relates to the trip and hold current. They mention "rated current", so they probably mean trip current?

EDIT: I realized I probably need a bidirectional TVS to also protect against reverse voltage, so should I use the SMBJ12CA instead?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, You'll need slightly more input power than output power. It depends on the efficiency of the converter as a whole. For example if it has an efficiency of say 90%, then you'll need about 1.4A at 12V (16.8W) at the input to get 5V 3A (15W) at the output. The extra power is used by the components to carry out the conversion, there would also be loses due to heat. That's why you would want to select an inductor with as low a DCR (direct current resistance) as possible and MOSFETS with as low an Rdson and gate charge (getting both low usually leads to more expensive devices) as possible (in your case with this controller, the MOSFETS are embedded so no choice to be made).
2. For me, I would just follow the typical application circuit that some manufacturers are nice enough to give. Your IC has one on page 15 of the datasheet that shows a circuit for your requirements of 5v 3A output. You could just go with that.

(On a side note these guys are pretty great for showing so many different circuits for different output options, I don't usually see that many!).

Comment: thanks, I'm already following the 12V in/5V out example from the MP1495S datasheet. What I need help with is in selecting the right fuse (PTC) and TVS to protect the input of the MP1495S.

Comment: Page 1 of the datahseet for the MP1495S says "Full protection features include over-current protection and thermal shut down.". I don't really think you need a PTC after that. As for the TVS, that looks like it would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. The fuse needs to have a rating of at least...

$$I_{FUSE} \ge V_{OUT} * I_{OUT} / V_{IN} / N$$
Where ...
I_FUSE is the rated fuse input current in Amps
V_OUT is the output voltage in Volts
I_OUT is the output current in Amps
N is the power supply efficiency

You need to consider the fact that the fuse will have tolerances and that the trip point will change with ambient temperature.  So, you need to consult the fuse datasheet to make sure that the rating still meets the above I_IN number under worst case tolerances and temperature.

2. The point of the fuse is to prevent a fire and protect the downstream components.  Therefore, the trip point for the fuse should also be lower than the rating for your main power path components (inductors, MOSFETs, and any ICs that current flows through).
3. If the fuse trips to often then it can be a nuisance for the user.  Therefore, you want to leave some margin between the maximum rated operating point for your supply and where the fuse actually trips, while also leaving margin for your components (point #2).
4. As for the TVS, the worst case would be that the supply output has zero load, and that the input voltage is above the normal input range.  In that case you could have current flowing through the fuse at any level up to the trip point of the fuse, and all that current would be flowing through the TVS.  In theory this could happen indefinitely.

Therefore, the wattage rating for the TVS must be at least...
$$ W_{TVS} \ge V_{TVS} * I_{FUSE}$$
$$ I_{TVS} \ge I_{FUSE}$$
Where...
W_TVS is the rated wattage of the TVS in your system (which may depend on board layout).
V_TVS is the maximum clamping voltage of the TVS at a current level of I_FUSE.  If you want to be conservative, you could use the TVS voltage value given in the datasheet at its peak current rating.
I_TVS is the TVS current rating as given in the datasheet.

Comment: the problem with all of these current ratings that you have mentioned here is that they are actual operating currents. I know you said "... at least...", but really there needs to be (depending on the application) double digit percentage of margin on top what you have said.

Comment: @RogerDodger I also did say to leave some margin, but I did not specify how much.